# problems with 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm unsure how to add the row with the exception of the first column.This is what I have so far.I'm trying to get the output to be  5=1+2+3,  7=1+2+4,  8=3+5+9 . I will put it in another array to record the difference.

```
 public class Main {
  static int[][] Array = { { 5, 1, 2, 3 }, { 7, 1, 2, 4 }, { 8,3,5,9 } };

  public int[] sum(int[][] array) {
    int index = 0;
    int temp[] = new int[array[index].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        sum += array[j][i];
      }
      temp[index] = sum;
      System.out.println("Index is: " + index + " Sum is: " + sum);
      index++;
    }
    return temp;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().sum(Array);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `sum()` method is intended to get the sum of elements in a row. But it will do that if you change `array[j][i]` with `array[i][j]`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        sum += array[j][i];
      }
```

to

```
for (int j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        sum += array[i][j];
      }
```

output:

```
Index is: 0 Sum is: 6
Index is: 1 Sum is: 7
Index is: 2 Sum is: 17
```

Comment: I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: I am getting the output , Did you change `array[i][j]` i and j??

Comment: I forgot to take off the <= and leave it as <

Comment: If i wanted to go on about it with printing the first column how would i do that.

Comment: want to print first integer in the output? then you can just do this before printing sum `System.out.println(array[index][0]);`

Answer (score 0):

never check `<=` when `i=0` just < is enough
change the this line

```
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        sum += array[j][i];
      }
```

to this

```
 for (int j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    sum += array[i][j];
  }
```

Comment: This wont work. output is `Index is: 0 Sum is: 5
Index is: 1 Sum is: 8
Index is: 2 Sum is: 16`